# Restore data from external drive to same computer with new operating system

Tags: windows-10, backup, crashplan

I've used Crashplan to create a backup for my data on my Windows 7 laptop. The backup location is an external drive. This is the path:

[image: backup location]

Then I've installed Windows 10 on my laptop, in the process I wiped my laptop its hard drive. So I did not upgrade to Windows 10 with all my files remaining on the laptop. My plan was to have a clean install and only restore the necessary files from the backup. So far so good...

When installation was complete I've installed CrashPlan but now I don't know how to restore the files. I clicked on the **Restore tab** and saw the name of my "old pc" and it said it was offline which is logical I think because I've got a brand new installation.

I tried to add the hard drive to backup destination like so:

[image: destination]

I found it weird that the underlined number was different from the one in the path but I didn't think much of it so I tried going to the Restore tab to restore files from that location. But I could not change from where I wanted to restore because my "old pc" was offline.

Then I did something stupid I think, **I deleted my old pc from the destinations** with the hope of seeing my external hard drive location in the Restore path but that wasn't the case... **There are no backup destinations available** (language is Dutch):

[image: no destination available]

**So my question is how do i get my external hard drive to show up in the restore tab?** I hope somebody can help me because the backup contains very precious data to me like travel video's, family pics, development data.

Note: I've tried renaming the folder "773835192060408644" to "819058829015207292" but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Have you followed the directions at https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Restoring/Download_files_from_an_external_drive_to_a_new_device_or_drive and you're unable to set destination folder (step 3)?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that software as will many of us. Paste the contents of crashplan_backup/773835192060408644

Comment: I found a solution thanks to the CrashPlan support, I'll post it later today. Thanks for willing to assist me.